# Can't paste file into windows partition - do I change permissions?

Tags: sudo

I have an external usb drive with files I want to access in windows, but they're not accessable in windows, but they are in ubuntu.

I want to copy-paste the files onto my windows drive, but the paste option is not available. I think it may be becasue I don't have permission to do so...

My ubuntu is on a USB stick, not installed... how would I be able to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit your question to provide info on the file system of the external USB. My first suspicion would be that the file system is not consistent and will need to be repaired and fixed. If it is ntfs, then have the USB checked using the Windows drive checking tool. Do this before attempting anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The disk drive what kind of FS have? normally in linux files create under the NTFS partition had owner root and 777 has permission, this ntfs-3g default options:

```
UUID=2E741DA1741D6D39   /media/data ntfs-3g     default,rw  0   0
...
/dev/sda1 on /media/data type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

and I had no problem to access data on both installation.

In conclusion yes, you change permission to it and windows should be able to access.

Comment: P.S. better to change permission from the linux system

Comment: That's what I was thinking - I'm not trying to access within windows, simply to get permission to access the windows drive to paste some folders into it...

Comment: SImpl changing permissions within the drive isn't working... I'm changing them, but they are reverting back to default immediately

Comment: Then just mount it using ntfs-3g, as you see I just mount with rw and default